# How to prevent button click from collapsing pane

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a ui-bootstrap pane (header & body) with a button on the header. Clicking the header area should collapse the body. Clicking the button should just activate an alert popup.  Unfortunately, clicking that button ALSO collapses the pane. I suspect that the pane behind the button is somehow capturing the click. How can I prevent this?

Here's the plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/teCnC7KtvlQtosZurlqD?p=preview

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" ng-click="vm.onClickHeader()">
    <span ng-hide="vm.collapsed" style="padding-top: 8px">
        <span ng-click="vm.onClickBtn()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></span>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="panel-body" ng-hide="vm.collapsed" style="padding: 2px; padding-right: 4px">
    <div>Click the button above to hide me!</div>
</div>
</div>


var app = angular.module('app');

app.directive('myPanel', MyPanel);
function MyPanel() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'my-panel.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: MyController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        scope: true
    };
};


function MyController() {
    this.collapsed = false;

    this.onClickBtn = function onClickBtn() {
        alert('click!')
    };

    this.onClickHeader = function(evt) {
        this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the click event is propagating up the DOM from the `<span>`. You can add a `$event.stopPropagation()` to your `ng-click` directive. (Some people don't like this because they feel it's "dirty" to add such code into a directive so you could always pass `$event` as a parameter on `vm.onClickBtn()` and call `.stopPropagation()` in your controller.)

```
<span ng-click="vm.onClickBtn(); $event.stopPropagation();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></span>
```

Comment: You beat me by 4 sec. +1

Comment: Thanks! Plunker updated (with the 'non-dirty' solution).

Answer (score 1):

On inner `ng-click` just stop event bubbling by calling `stopPropagation` on $event object.

```
<span ng-click="vm.onClickBtn();$event.stopPropagation()">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
</span>
```

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TuO8izGQHqZN70DVV4IS?p=preview)